# Transforming ActiveRecord validation errors into API consumable errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, api, activerecord

I'm writing a pretty standard CRUD RESTful API in Rails 4. I'm coming up short on error handling though.

Imagine I have the following model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

If I try to create a book object without a title I'll get the following error:

```
{
  "title": [
    "can't be blank"
  ]
}
```

ActiveRecord validations are designed to be used with Forms. Ideally I'd like to match up each human readable validation error with a constant that can be used by an API consumer. So something like:

```
{
  "title": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "error_code": "TITLE_ERROR"
}
```

This can be both used to display user facing errors (*"title can't be blank"*) and can be used within other code (`if response.error_code === TITLE_ERROR`...). Is there any tooling for this in Rails?

EDIT: Here's a [very similar question from Rails 2 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933864/pattern-for-translating-activerecord-validation-errors-to-api-responses).

Comment: Could you had some of controller code. Is it the same code for API and your app requests? Because you are showing us your validation on the model, but I think your problem should be handled on the controller.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On **error_codes.yml** define your standard API errors, including `status_code`, `title`, `details` and an internal `code` you can then use to provide further info about the error on your API documentation.

Here's a basic example:

```
api:
  invalid_resource:
    code: '1'
    status: '400'
    title: 'Bad Request'

not_found:
    code: '2'
    status: '404'
    title: 'Not Found'
    details: 'Resource not found.'
```

On **config/initializers/api_errors.rb** load that YAML file into a constant.

```
API_ERRORS = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('doc','error-codes.yml'))['api']
```

On **app/controllers/concerns/error_handling.rb** define a reusable method to render your API errors in JSON format:

```
module ErrorHandling
  def respond_with_error(error, invalid_resource = nil)
    error = API_ERRORS[error]
    error['details'] = invalid_resource.errors.full_messages if invalid_resource
    render json: error, status: error['status']
  end
end
```

On your API base controller include the concern so it's available on all the controllers which inherit from it:

```
include ErrorHandling
```

You will then be able to use your method on any of those controllers:

```
respond_with_error('not_found') # For standard API errors
respond_with_error('invalid_resource', @user) # For invalid resources
```

For example on your users controller you may have the following:

```
def create
  if @user.save(your_api_params)
    # Do whatever your API needs to do
  else
    respond_with_error('invalid_resource', @user)
  end
end
```

The errors your API will output will look like this:

```
# For invalid resources
{
  "code": "1",
  "status": "400",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "details": [
    "Email format is incorrect"
  ]
}

# For standard API errors
{
  "code": "2",
  "status": "404",
  "title": "Not Found",
  "details": "Route not found."
}
```

As your API grows, you'll be able to easily add new error codes on your YAML file and use them with this method avoiding duplication and making your error codes consistent across your API.

Comment: Glad you liked it! Would you mind accepting the answer? :)

Comment: I'm still pondering how to marry this to the validation code.

Comment: Oh, this method relies on [Active Record Validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html), and lists the resulting errors in an array in case the resource is invalid.

Just define the validations as usual in your model and you'll be all set.

Comment: @EightyEight have you had the chance to try this out? Please let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: I must be missing something still. Who invokes `respond_with_error('invalid_resource', user) `? Are you suggesting the `unless user.save respond_with_error('invalid_resource', user)`?

Comment: @EightyEight that's exactly right. I've just updated my answer to include an example for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Comment: I'd recommend sending `errors.messages` hash instead of `errors.full_messages` array. This way you can map those errors to the corresponding fields in the UI.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
book = Book.new(book_params)
if user.save
  render json: book, status: 201
else
  render json: { 
           errors: book.errors,
           error_codes: book.errors.keys.map { |f| f.upcase + "_ERROR" }
         },
         status: 422
end
```

The `error_codes` will return multiple error codes.

Answer (score 2):

Your create method should look just something like this:

```
def create
  book = Book.new(book_params)
  if user.save
    render json: book, status: 201
  else
    render json: { errors: book.errors, error_code: "TITLE_ERROR" }, status: 422
  end
end
```

That would return json that looks like what you're asking, except that "title" and "error_code" would be nested within "errors." Not a big issue to deal with I hope.

Comment: I'd like to generalize this so that validation errors correspond to error codes somehow. Imagine I add a bunch of other fields, `author`, `isbn`, `price`.

Comment: You can structure the hash however you want, and even nest that as well. `render json: { author: book.author, somemore_stuff: { isbn: 12345, price: "$55"}, error_code: "bad stuff", a_thing: a_thing_variable }` It'll be converted to json the way you expect.

Answer (score 2):

It seem's like you are not considering multiple validation errors.

In your example the `Book` model has just one validation, but other models may have more validations.

My answer contains a first solution that accounts for multiple validations and another solution that uses only the first validation error found on the model

## Solution 1 - Handling multiple validations

Add this in your ApplicationController

```
# Handle validation errors
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exception|
  messages = exception.record.errors.messages
  messages[:error_codes] = messages.map {|k,v| k.to_s.upcase << "_ERROR" }
  render json: messages, status: 422
end
```

note that `error_codes` in this case is an array to allow multiple error codes. eg:

```
{
  "title": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "author": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "error_codes": ["TITLE_ERROR", "AUTHOR_ERROR"]
}
```

## Solution 2 - Handling only the first validation error

If you really want to keep only a single validation error, use this instead

```
# Handle validation errors
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exception|
  key = exception.record.errors.messages.keys[0]
  msg = exception.record.errors.messages[key]
  render json: { key => msg, :error_code => key.to_s.upcase << "_ERROR" }, status: 422
end
```

which will give you a response like

```
{
  "title": [
    "can't be blank"
  ],
  "error_code": "TITLE_ERROR"
}
```

even when you have multiple errors

Answer (score 1):

You have only 2 ways of achieving this : either you write code for the validators (components that will test for error during validation) or either you write renderers.

I assume you know how to write renderers as @baron816's answer is suggesting, and do some DRY to *somehow* generalize it.

Let me walk you through the validator technique:

**1-** Let's create a storage for your error codes, I call them `custom_error_codes` and I assume you can set multiple error codes at once so I'll use an `Array` (you change that otherwise).

Create a model concern

```
module ErrorCodesConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    # storage for the error codes
    attr_reader :custom_error_codes
    # reset error codes storage when validation process starts
    before_validation :clear_error_codes
  end

  # default value so the variable is not empty when accessed improperly 
  def custom_error_codes
    @custom_error_codes ||= []
  end

  private 
  def clear_error_codes
    @custom_error_codes = []
  end
end
```

Then add the concern to your models

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ErrorCodesConcern
  ...
end
```

**2-** Let's hack validators to add the marking of error codes. First we need to look at the validators source code, they are located in *(activemodel-gem-path)/lib/active_model/validations/*.

Create a *validators* directory in your *app* directory, then create the following validator

```
class CustomPresenceValidator < ActiveModel::Validations::PresenceValidator
  # this method is copied from the original validator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    if value.blank?
      record.errors.add(attr_name, :blank, options) 
      # Those lines are our customization where we add the error code to the model
      error_code = "#{attr_name.upcase}_ERROR"
      record.custom_error_codes << error_code unless record.custom_error_codes.include? error_code
    end
  end
end
```

Then use our custom validator in our models

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, custom_presence: true
end
```

**3-** So you have to modify all rails validators that your code is using and create renderers (see @baron816's answer) and response with the model's `custom_error_codes` value.

Comment: Thanks, that's much closer to what I was trying to achieve. Is there a way to reuse existing validators without manually extending them? It'll be too much effort to extend them manually.

Comment: Maybe you can try to hack (on the same principle) `ActiveModel::Errors#add`, which seems to reduce the effort on the short term, but I personally would feel safer on the long term to hack the validators. And they are just a few of them, should take a couple of minutes to achieve.